# The prince and princess or The prince and the princess

Tags: articles, exam-questions

> The prince and princess (A) made their way (B) through the cheering crowd. (C) No error (D)

According to my book the above sentence is a no error sentence but isn't the first part in the sentence wrong ? Since the prince and the princess are two different persons don't we need to use article *the* with both of them ?

Comment: You wouldn't normally capitalise *prince, princess, king, queen* in such contexts today, but it's really something of a stylistic choice - not something that over-enthusiastic exam setters should concern themselves with under the guise of testing knowledge of English as a second language. The same applies to whether or not to repeat the article (you *could*, but usually people wouldn't).

Comment: Sorry , let me edit the question.

Comment: No, there is no need to repeat the the. Imagine the context: The prince and princess [of some place]. No the. The "of some place" is implied. The president and vice-president of the association. The boy and girl in the house. When the article goes with two items "belonging" to the same thing, you do not need it.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, if the two are associated with the same *thing* the second "***the***" is not necessary since the two might be considered  single *unit*.  Unless you wanted to *emphasize* / *draw attention* to a particular aspect in which case "*both*" might also be used.

> **The** prince and **the** princess of Britain *both* have dark hair.
>
> **The** prince and princess are the parents of George and Charlotte.
>
> **The** ham and eggs are grown locally.
>   **The** ham and **the** eggs are *(both)* grown locally.

Comment: I don't buy the both business. Eggs are not grown by the way. They are laid by hens. Perhaps produced is better....